# is it required to install VM virtual box while i am installing Genymotion for appium

Tags: android, windows, virtual-machine, appium, genymotion

Actually i am doing Appium for my practice in office laptop. While i am installing VM virtual box it asking for reset of server connection. Because of that i may face an issue's. Can you guys please suggest me how can i proceed with this.

While i am executing my code it's giving below error message as unreachable server.

Below code i have used for execution.

```
DesiredCapabilities capability=DesiredCapabilities.android();
    capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.CHROME);
    capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.ANDROID);
    capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "ANDROID");
    capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "my phone");
    capability.`setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "version");
    URL url=new URL("http://127.0.01:4723/wd/hub");
    WebDriver driver=new AndroidDriver(url,capability);
    driver.get("www.facebook.com");
    System.out.println("Page title is :"+ driver.getCurrentUrl())
```

Comment: Are you executing script also on Same VM? Start your appium server by configuring details. Execute "adb devices" command from CMD, it will give you device id. Use that device id as Device_Name.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I didn't installed VM virtual box. I have installed only appium tool. Is it mandatory to install Vm box and now it's giving an error as New Session couldn't be created.

Comment: It is not mandatory to install VM for  appium , can you give detail on what you have done and what error you are facing?

Comment: I have installed below tools: 1.Android sdk    2. Node JS    3.Appium    4.java client jar   5. Genymotion   .......and i have executed by using above script.. i am getting this exception.....Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception

Comment: Suggestion: before writing any code in java for Appium, first try to use Appium GUI and try to connect to device. When You achieve connection, write code.